# How to stretch jQuery slider to its contents

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to stretch jQuery slider to its contents.

```
<div id="slider">1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 </div>​
```

.

```
$("#slider").slider({ max:10,});​
```

.

```
#slider
{
margin:20px;
max-width:400px; 
}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U2e77/

Only when I add display:table-cell; to slider class I get the desired behavior, but it doesn't work in Firefox and looks like not to be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display:inline` did the same result as `display:table-cell`, is this what you want?

EDIT

if you need it to behave like a block element, use `display: inline-block`